# Help wiring a new light

Tags: wiring, lighting, bathroom

Good day everyone

I need some assistance with wiring a new light. All other wire outlets in the house have a standard brown (live), blue (neutral) and green (earth) cable apart from this one (see picture). This light fitting has a black, red, 2 x green and another grey wire that seems to be solid copper. The black and one green come from one part of the outlet, the red, grey and the other green from another part and the solid grey is seperate from the rest.

The light has a brown and blue wire and a connection for a earth cable. Please can someone tell me how to connect this light. [image]

Comment: Hi. When i moved in there was no old light. The fitting was left bare. I need to connect the new light to these wires

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Im in the Netherlands. I hope that helps